# animation with video - flash substitute for tablets

Tags: flash, animation, video

I have a project (a website) where I am supposed to create an interactive animation that will contain a movie and over it a few graphical elements that include text and some geometrical shapes.

The animation should contain user controls that will allow the user to navigate back and forth. I can do this very simply in Flash, but however the website should be accessible also from tablets and Flash does not work on those.

The idea is that I do not know what approach should I get to this project and I hope I can find some advice here.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's something simple you can try to publish to Android/iOS using Flash/Flash Builder(using AIR). 
Depending on your experience with javascript and how complex the project is, you might want to try code it straight in HTML using Canvas. 
The [CreateJS Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/flash-to-html5.html) might help with assets a bit.

Another option would be using [Haxe](http://haxe.org/): the syntax is very similar to actionscript and you can either target native iOS/Android using [NME](http://www.nme.io/developer/tutorials/) or to HTML5. Haxe/NME has a pretty impressive performance compared to the Flash IDE when it comes to compiling.

Comment: Thank you for that. I do not have a very much experience into AIR or HaXe but I guess it might be a good starting point.